# Jquery Mobile Word wrap text comming from textarea

Tags: html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

What does a phone wrap text with after inserting into a HTML textarea ?

I tested several things, but i just cant get my wordwrap working.

If i input a text like

```
 b
 c
 a
```

it will get out as one line "b c a".

I have a HTML P tag, but the text from the Textarea wont get the newlines with it.

I tried:

```
replace("\n", "<br />");
CSS worp wrap rules
```

Any ideas ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And i fixed it myself :) white-space: pre-wrap; this CSS rule i somehow missed :)

Comment: I did correct my errors in my cide and the following answer i provided is the answer to my question.